# DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I got a lot of errors with the message :

> "DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"

after changed from python-psycopg to python-psycopg2 as Django project's database engine.

The code remains the same, just don't know where those errors are from.

Comment: I'm curious what was your final resolution to this problem? I'm having this same issue, but since my hosting provider doesn't log query errors it's been impossible so far to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I finally tracked my issue down to a bug when using a database table as the cache backend. Django bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11569 StackOverflow discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189541/django-cache-set-causing-duplicate-key-error

Comment: FYI If you're just using psycopg2 without django, `conn.rollback()` (where conn is your connection object) will clear the error so you can run other queries

Answer (score 261, accepted):

This is what postgres does when a query produces an error and you try to run another query without first rolling back the transaction.  (You might think of it as a safety feature, to keep you from corrupting your data.)

To fix this, you'll want to figure out where in the code that bad query is being executed.  It might be helpful to use the [log_statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) and [log_min_error_statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-ERROR-STATEMENT) options in your postgresql server.

Comment: the problem is when I was using python-psycopg, no such errors raised. does psycopg2 implemented a different mechanism talking to postgres?

Comment: The method of talking to the server probably doesn't matter, but it's possible that the version you used before somehow defaulted to autocommit mode while the new version does not.  The error might still have occurred, but you could more easily have missed it.  It's also possible that data type conversion or something else has changed since the old version.  Regardless, the best fix is to track down the bad query so you can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: in psycopg: `conn.rollback()`

Comment: This is late, but my issue was that an error was thrown in a try except block and then a subsequent query was made on the same connection

Comment: @JasonHolden this is so True. When i run my connection and cursor in a loop, it did not work because my try, exception were not positioned correctly. I think i will raise an issue about this asap. the Try Except was creating a kind of silent error difficult to see. thanks to your comment I was able to make it work!

Answer (score 151):

To get rid of the error, **roll back the last (erroneous) transaction** after you've fixed your code:

```py
from django.db import transaction
transaction.rollback()
```

You can use try-except to prevent the error from occurring:

```py
from django.db import transaction, DatabaseError
try:
    a.save()
except DatabaseError:
    transaction.rollback()
```

Refer : [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#transaction-rollback)

Comment: This addresses the core issue and lets you recover after a statement that caused the aborted transaction.

Comment: this, combined with try / except.

Comment: Why use `IntegrityError` and not the base class `DatabaseError`?

Comment: For some reason I had to move the rollback outside of the "except" section.  I was using .bulk_create() and not .save()

Comment: Worked with django 1.4.16 after following this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15753000/573034

Answer (score 90):

In Flask you just need to write:

```
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("ROLLBACK")
conn.commit()
```

P.S. Documentation goes here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-rollback.html

Comment: This solution is also of great help when the error occurs in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Nice. It helped me in Jupyter

Comment: Worth adding that this works outside of Flask and seemingly anywhere you're using psycopg2

Answer (score 52):

So, I ran into this same issue. The problem I was having here was that my database wasn't properly synced. Simple problems always seem to cause the most angst...

To sync your django db, from within your app directory, within terminal, type:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

Edit: Note that if you are using django-south, running the '$ python manage.py migrate' command may also resolve this issue.

Happy coding!

Comment: Upvoted for stating the obvious. I wouldn't give this more than one upvote though because it was probably not the answer sought.

Comment: I fixed it a similar way by `python manage.py migrate <app>`... for all my apps.

Comment: @Clayton - you don't say, but I assume you're using `django-south`  - the `migrate` command is not built into django.

Comment: @GregBall- That is correct... I am using django-south. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: I'm getting this error when doing syncdb - I think it's to do with the order django goes through the tables.

Comment: @Clayton - thanks for the note, updated answer to reflect your point

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem too, when working with `easy_thumbnails`.

Comment: Had this too. I simply forgot that the table I was querying wasn't created yet in the database.

Answer (score 40):

In my experience, these errors happen this way:

```
try:
    code_that_executes_bad_query()
    # transaction on DB is now bad
except:
    pass

# transaction on db is still bad
code_that_executes_working_query() # raises transaction error
```

There nothing wrong with the second query, but since the real error was caught, the second query is the one that raises the (much less informative) error.

edit: this only happens if the `except` clause catches `IntegrityError` (or any other low level database exception), If you catch something like `DoesNotExist` this error will not come up, because `DoesNotExist` does not corrupt the transaction.

The lesson here is don't do try/except/pass.

Answer (score 17):

I think the pattern priestc mentions is more likely to be the usual cause of this issue when using PostgreSQL.

However I feel there are valid uses for the pattern and I don't think this issue should be a reason to always avoid it. For example:

```
try:
    profile = user.get_profile()
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    profile = make_default_profile_for_user(user)

do_something_with_profile(profile)
```

If you do feel OK with this pattern, but want to avoid explicit transaction handling code all over the place then you might want to look into turning on autocommit mode (PostgreSQL 8.2+): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#autocommit-mode

```
DATABASES['default'] = {
    #.. you usual options...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'autocommit': True,
    }
}
```

I am unsure if there are important performance considerations (or of any other type).

Answer (score 14):

just use rollback

Example code

```
try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2 (id serial, qa text);")
except:
    cur.execute("rollback")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2 (id serial, qa text);")
```

Answer (score 12):

You only need to run

```
rollback;
```

in PostgreSQL and that's it!

Answer (score 8):

I've just got a similar error here. I've found the answer in this link https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/transaction/

```py
client = PsqlConnection(config)
connection = client.connection
cursor = client.cursor

try:
   for query in list_of_querys:
      #query format => "INSERT INTO <database.table> VALUES (<values>)"
      cursor.execute(query)
      connection.commit()
except BaseException as e:
   connection.rollback()
```

Doing this the following query's you send to postgresql will not return an error.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 7):

If you get this while in interactive shell and need a quick fix, do this:

```
from django.db import connection
connection._rollback()
```

originally seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7753748/484127)

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar behavior while running a malfunctioned transaction on the `postgres` terminal. Nothing went through after this, as the `database` is in a state of `error`. However, just as a quick fix, if you can afford to avoid `rollback transaction`. Following did the trick for me:

`COMMIT;`

Comment: I was in a repl, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I've got the silimar problem. The solution was to migrate db (`manage.py syncdb` or `manage.py schemamigration --auto <table name>` if you use south).

Answer (score 5):

In Flask shell, all I needed to do was a `session.rollback()` to get past this.

Answer (score 2):

I have met this issue , the error comes out since the error transactions hasn't been ended rightly, I found the `postgresql_transactions` of Transaction Control command [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions.htm)

**Transaction Control**

The following commands are used to control transactions

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION − To start a transaction.

COMMIT − To save the changes, alternatively you can use END TRANSACTION command.

ROLLBACK − To rollback the changes.
```

so i use the `END TRANSACTION` to end the error TRANSACTION, code like this:

```
    for key_of_attribute, command in sql_command.items():
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        g_logger.info("execute command :%s" % (command))
        try:
            cursor.execute(command)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            g_logger.info("the command:%s result is :%s" % (command, rows))
            result_list[key_of_attribute] = rows
            g_logger.info("result_list is :%s" % (result_list))
        except Exception as e:
            cursor.execute('END TRANSACTION;')
            g_logger.info("error command :%s and error is :%s" % (command, e))
    return result_list
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the python package psycopg2 and I got this error while querying.
I kept running just the query and then the execute function, but when I reran the connection (shown below), it resolved the issue. So rerun what is above your script i.e the connection, because as someone said above, I think it lost the connection or was out of sync or something.

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "##",
        password = "##",
        host = "##",
        port = "##",
        database = "##")
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Comment: Wasted almost an hour, just to realize that restarting the kernel (not sure if kernel restart was needed) and re-running all the cells did it for me.

Comment: glad I could help! It's good to know restarting the kernel works too!

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error too but it was masking another more relevant error message where the code was trying to store a 125 characters string in a 100 characters column:

```
DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(100)
```

I had to debug through the code for the above message to show up, otherwise it displays

```
DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to @priestc and @Sebastian, what if you do something like this?

```
try:
    conn.commit()
except:
    pass

cursor.execute( sql )
try: 
    return cursor.fetchall()
except: 
    conn.commit()
    return None
```

I just tried this code and it seems to work, failing silently without having to care about any possible errors, and working when the query is good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @AnujGupta's answer is correct. However the rollback can itself raise an exception which you should catch and handle:

```
from django.db import transaction, DatabaseError
try:
    a.save()
except DatabaseError:
    try:
        transaction.rollback()
    except transaction.TransactionManagementError:
        # Log or handle otherwise
```

If you find you're rewriting this code in various `save()` locations, you can extract-method:

```
import traceback
def try_rolling_back():
    try:
        transaction.rollback()
        log.warning('rolled back')  # example handling
    except transaction.TransactionManagementError:
        log.exception(traceback.format_exc())  # example handling
```

Finally, you can prettify it using a decorator that protects methods which use `save()`:

```
from functools import wraps
def try_rolling_back_on_exception(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            try_rolling_back()
    return wrapped

@try_rolling_back_on_exception
def some_saving_method():
    # ...
    model.save()
    # ...
```

Even if you implement the decorator above, it's still convenient to keep `try_rolling_back()` as an extracted method in case you need to use it manually for cases where specific handling is required, and the generic decorator handling isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange behavior for me. I'm surprised that no one thought of savepoints. In my code failing query was expected behavior:

```
from django.db import transaction
@transaction.commit_on_success
def update():
    skipped = 0
    for old_model in OldModel.objects.all():
        try:
            Model.objects.create(
                group_id=old_model.group_uuid,
                file_id=old_model.file_uuid,
            )
        except IntegrityError:
            skipped += 1
    return skipped
```

I have changed code this way to use savepoints:

```
from django.db import transaction
@transaction.commit_on_success
def update():
    skipped = 0
    sid = transaction.savepoint()
    for old_model in OldModel.objects.all():
        try:
            Model.objects.create(
                group_id=old_model.group_uuid,
                file_id=old_model.file_uuid,
            )
        except IntegrityError:
            skipped += 1
            transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
        else:
            transaction.savepoint_commit(sid)
    return skipped
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with bad sql execution which does not allow other queries to execute until the previous one gets suspended/rollback.

In PgAdmin4-4.24 there is an option of rollback, one can try this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mine is solved by setting connection.autocommit = True.

I am using psycopg2 with AWS Redshift.