# Rails 3.x How to write update all based on row value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like the following SQL query to be executed in a migration file after adding a column (updating the new field with existing column value from the same row)

```
UPDATE users SET last_login=updated_at;
```

The SQL statements work properly when executed on the database, but in rails I tried multiple syntax using the ActiveRecord update_all method but without success

```
User.update_all("last_login=updated_at")
```

I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: UPDATE "users" SET last_login=updated_at
```

Obviously something is missing in my syntax, but can't figure out what.
Can anyone point me to the right syntax?

Regards/J.

Comment: Can it be some validation problem, like the example on this link?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations

Comment: Could have been, but in that case was not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax is indeed correct, the issue was relying in the fact that I had to rollback the previous [transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979369/databaseerror-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra).

```
User.update_all("last_login=updated_at")
```

This statement works properly.