# How to create PostgreSQL savePoint with Reactor and Spring

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

[io.r2dbc.spi.Connection](https://r2dbc.io/spec/0.8.0.RC1/api/io/r2dbc/spi/Connection.html) and [PostgresqlConnection](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/blob/main/src/main/java/io/r2dbc/postgresql/PostgresqlConnection.java) have `createSavepoint`, `releaseSavepoint` and `rollbackTransactionToSavepoint` methods.
How can I use these method by having `R2dbcTransactionManager` and `TransactionalOperator`?

I want to create an idempotent service which tries to insert to a table, if a unique constraint is violated then selects the existing record and continues with that

```
Mono.just(newOrder)
    .flatMap(order -> orderRepository.save(order)
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> orderRepository.findByUniqueField(newOrder.uniqueField))

    .otherProcesses...
    .as(transactionalOperator::transactional)
```

And I receive `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block` from PostgreSQL

I saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48771320/5275087 but it seams `autosave=always` doesn't work with r2dbc

I wanted to try something like:

```
transactionalOperator.execute(reactiveTransaction -> {
  GenericReactiveTransaction genericReactiveTransaction = (GenericReactiveTransaction) reactiveTransaction;
  ConnectionFactoryTransactionObject txObject = (ConnectionFactoryTransactionObject) genericReactiveTransaction.getTransaction();
  Connection connection = txObject.getConnectionHolder().getConnection();
  return Mono.from(connection.createSavepoint(TRANSACTION_LEVEL_1))
            .then(Mono.just(newOrder)
                .flatMap(order -> orderRepository.save(order)
                    .onErrorResume(throwable ->
                        Mono.from(connection.rollbackTransactionToSavepoint(TRANSACTION_LEVEL_1))
                            .then(orderRepository.findByUniqueField(newOrder.uniqueField)))
                ));
```

But `R2dbcTransactionManager.ConnectionFactoryTransactionObject` is a private class.

How do I achieve this without using reflection