# Facing SQL state [25P02]; error code [0] in spring integration flow while performing update

Tags: postgresql, spring-integration

After looking at the logs we found that the exception occurred in
"UPDATE INT_MESSAGE_GROUP set UPDATED_DATE=? where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?"
But the error code thrown was '0', so spring integration class couldn't catch the proper exception and the exception was propagated to the top of hierarchy and got catched in super class Exception.
So, we suspect that the issue was either in spring integration flow that it wasn't able to catch the uncategorized error or was it the PostgresDB which was culprit in throwing no error code.

It will be highly appreciable if I can get some help here. Please tell if anything else is required from my side.

I am attaching the detailed log captured in our code.

Here is the log printed :

```
{
"preview": false,
"offset": 913,
"result": {


"_raw": "{\"ts\":\"04 20 2022 
03:10:25.763\",\"th\":\"task-scheduler-1\",\"falcon_host\":\"\",\"tenant\":\"\",\"user\":\"SysAdmin\",\"trxid\":\"469972d9-2f
c7-4525-aaaf-8e88ff4d5fa9\",\"level\":\"ERROR\",\"logger\":\"org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler\",\"msg\"
:\"org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 
'org.springframework.integration.config.AggregatorFactoryBean#0' for component 'aggregator'; defined in: 'class path 
resource [callbackProvisioning.xml]'; from source: ''int:aggregator' with id='aggregator'']; nested exception is 

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE 
INT_MESSAGE_GROUP set UPDATED_DATE=? where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]; SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]; ERROR: current 
transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block; nested exception is com.edb.util.PSQLException: 

ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block, failedMessage=GenericMessage 
[payload=TenantProvisionRequestStatusDTO [id=1322507, name=null, tenantProvisionRequestId=103916, service=WFMDB, displayService=WFM Database, status=pending, displayProvisionStatus=Pending, creationDate=2022-04-20 03:10:00.359, modifyDate=2022-04-20 03:10:00.359, description=null, serviceId=-12, provisionJson=null, isRecoverable=true, retryCount=0, nextRetryTime=null, subStatus=null], headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[b8ed4772-5c4b-01c6-3453-6368b2b430d7, 2, 2]], requestType=callback, sequenceSize=2, correlationId=aab63e4c-9809-ad0d-62a9-d9c3c6750dca, id=cfc77b00-1d3f-88d9-5d10-d4b487763aed, timestamp=1650424222608}]  at
org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192) at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)  
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)  
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)  
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)  
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)  
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)  
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)  
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)  
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)  
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)  
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:445)\\n\\tatorg.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)  
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:445) at  org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:319)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)  
at  org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:311)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)at  org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:140)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)  
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)  
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)  
at  
org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)  
at  org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:213)  
at  org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:195)  
at  org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:445) at  org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:319)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:23  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMess
ageHandler.java:140)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)  
at  org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:445) at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:319)  
at  org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)  
at  org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:311)  
at  org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:140)  
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)  
at  org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)  atorg.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)  
at  org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)  
at  org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)  
at  org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:196)
at  org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:444)  
at  org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:428)  
at  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
at  org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)  
at  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)  
at  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)  
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)  
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)  
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)  
at  org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)  
at  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy338.call(Unknown Source)  
at  org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:376)  
at  org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$3(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:323)  
at  org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)  
at  org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)  
at  org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)  
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:320)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)  
at  org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)  
at  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)  
at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)  
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  
at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\\nCaused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE INT_MESSAGE_GROUP set UPDATED_DATE=? where 
GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]; SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]; ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until 
end of transaction block; nested exception is com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands 
ignored until end of transaction block  at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1542)  at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)  at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)  at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)  at
org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcMessageStore.doUpdateMessageGroup(JdbcMessageStore.java:635)  at
org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcMessageStore.addMessagesToGroup(JdbcMessageStore.java:361)  at
org.springframework.integration.store.AbstractMessageGroupStore.addMessageToGroup(AbstractMessageGroupStore.java:189)
at 
org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.store(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:780
)  
at
org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.processMessageForGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessag
eHandler.java:495)  
at
org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessage
Handler.java:474)  
at
org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)\\n\\t... 119 
more\\nCaused by: com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of 
transaction block  atcom.edb.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2759)  
at
com.edb.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2376)  
at
com.edb.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:347)  
at
com.edb.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:510)  
at
com.edb.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:427)  
at
com.edb.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:175)  
at
com.edb.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:141)  
at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor268.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  at
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementDecoratorInterceptor$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementDecoratorInterceptor.jav
a:237)  atcom.sun.proxy.$Proxy290.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)  
at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor268.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  at
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)  
at
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy290.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)  
at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965)  
at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)\\n\\t... 128 more\\nCaused by: 
com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \\\"message_group_pk\\\"\\n  Detail: Key 
(group_key, region)=(254b6008-0fd7-3c10-b142-2a2e4f1841d8, DEFAULT) already exists.  
at
com.edb.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2759)  
at
com.edb.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2376)  
at
com.edb.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:347)  
at
com.edb.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:510)  
at
com.edb.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:427)  at
com.edb.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:175)  
at
com.edb.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:141)  
at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor268.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
at
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementDecoratorInterceptor$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementDecoratorInterceptor.jav
a:237)  atcom.sun.proxy.$Proxy290.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)  
at
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor268.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  at
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)  
at
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy290.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)  
at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965)  
at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)  
at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)  
at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)  
at
org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcMessageStore.doCreateMessageGroup(JdbcMessageStore.java:623)  
at
org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcMessageStore.addMessagesToGroup(JdbcMessageStore.java:357)\\n\\t... 124 

more\\n\"  }",
    "_time": "2022-04-20T03:10:25.763+0000",
    "date_hour": "3",
    "date_mday": "20",
    "date_minute": "10",
    "date_month": "april",
    "date_second": "25",
    "date_wday": "wednesday",
    "date_year": "2022",
    "date_zone": "local",
    "falcon_host": "",
    "host": "cust01-gss01-tms10-app-1648100547-1.int.gss.mykronos.com",
    "index": "cust-prd-wfd-tms-app",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "linecount": "1",
    "logger": "org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler",
    "msg": "org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.AggregatorFactoryBean#0' for component 'aggregator'; defined in: 'class path resource [callbackProvisioning.xml]'; from source: ''int:aggregator' with id='aggregator'']; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE INT_MESSAGE_GROUP set UPDATED_DATE=? where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]; SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]; ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block; nested exception is 
    com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=TenantProvisionRequestStatusDTO [id=1322507, name=null, tenantProvisionRequestId=103916, service=WFMDB, displayService=WFM Database, status=pending, displayProvisionStatus=Pending, creationDate=2022-04-20 03:10:00.359, modifyDate=2022-04-20 03:10:00.359, description=null, serviceId=-12, provisionJson=null, isRecoverable=true, retryCount=0, nextRetryTime=null, subStatus=null], headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[b8ed4772-5c4b-01c6-3453-6368b2b430d7, 2, 2]], requestType=callback, sequenceSize=2, correlationId=aab63e4c-9809-ad0d-62a9-d9c3c6750dca, id=cfc77b00-1d3f-88d9-5d10-d4b487763aed, timestamp=1650424222608}] org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
    \more\n",
    "source": "/data/tomcat/logs/tms.log",
    "sourcetype": "tms:app",
    "splunk_server": "cust01-prd01-log01-idx-210330-09.int.oss.mykronos.com",
    "tenant": "",
    "th": "task-scheduler-1",
    "trxid": "469972d9-2fc7-4525-aaaf-8e88ff4d5fa9",
    "ts": "04 20 2022 03:10:25.763",
    "user": "SysAdmin"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reformat the stack trace so it would be more readable over here? Right now I see new line breakers in the middle of sentences

Comment: Error stack trace is formatted now, i hope its readable now. thanks @ArtemBilan

Comment: Why error is JSON? It cannot be a plain log message. Where did you take this message from? What the tool breaks a simple readable stack trace? `at` usually goes on a new line when stack trace is printed: https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-read-and-understand-a-java-stacktrace

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan, there is no mechanism in our production system to get the logs other than JSON, but I have formatted it now to my best to make it more readable.

Comment: Do you use a transaction manager for your logic? It looks like we have failed with the `DuplicateKeyException` then we try to update a group instead: `logger.warn("Lost race to create group; attempting update instead", e);`. In this case it looks like PostgreSQL has marked a transaction as aborted and therefore we fail again on the `UPDATE`.

Comment: See if you can configure your PostgreSQL to not `autocommit`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399727/psqlexception-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra