# How bad are savepoints in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

We are in process of migrating exisiting java application from Oracle DB to PostgreSQL and recently we have noticed following "unexpected" behaviour from PostgreSQL:

session#1:

```sql
db=> begin;
BEGIN
db=*> select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_s where r_object_id='08000000800027d6' for update;
   r_object_id    
------------------
 08000000800027d6
```

session#2:

```
db=> begin;
BEGIN
db=*> select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_s where r_object_id='08000000800027d6' for update nowait;
ERROR:  could not obtain lock on row in relation "dm_sysobject_s"
db=!> select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_s where r_object_id='08000000800027d6' for update nowait;
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

while in Oracle everything works as expected:

session#1:

```
SQL> set autocommit off;
SQL> select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_s where r_object_id='0800012d80000122' for update;

R_OBJECT_ID
----------------
0800012d80000122
```

session#2:

```
SQL> set autocommit off;
SQL> select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_s where r_object_id='0800012d80000122' for update nowait;
select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_s where r_object_id='0800012d80000122' for update nowait
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired


SQL> select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_s where r_object_id='0800012d80000122' for update nowait;
select r_object_id from dm_sysobject_s where r_object_id='0800012d80000122' for update nowait
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired


SQL> commit;
```

I already read [PSQLException: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399727/psqlexception-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra) topic, and got an understanding that the only way to preserve previous Oracle behaviour (i.e. keeping transaction active after unsuccessful attempt to lock row) in DB layer is to use savepoints. Ok, so far so good, and the code below is doing what is expected at least in cases when `Supplier<T> supplier` is performing DB operations only (I do understand the risks of getting discrepancies between DB and persistence context in case when I perform more sophisticated operations backed up by savepoint):

```java
@Override
public <T> T withSavepoint(SessionImplementor session, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return session.doReturningWork(connection -> {
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
        if (!metaData.supportsSavepoints()) {
            return supplier.get();
        }
        boolean success = false;
        Savepoint savepoint = null;
        try {
            savepoint = connection.setSavepoint();
            T result = supplier.get();
            success = true;
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (savepoint != null) {
                if (!success) {
                    connection.rollback(savepoint);
                }
                connection.releaseSavepoint(savepoint);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

After some research I have discovered that implementation of savepoints in `PostgreSQL` may cause severe performance issues, for example:

- [Why we spent the last month eliminating PostgreSQL subtransactions](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/09/29/why-we-spent-the-last-month-eliminating-postgresql-subtransactions/)
- [PostgreSQL Subtransactions and performance](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/subtransactions-and-performance-in-postgresql/)
- [PostgreSQL Subtransactions Considered Harmful](https://postgres.ai/blog/20210831-postgresql-subtransactions-considered-harmful)

However, none of those blogposts actually provide information about what savepoint patters are safe and which aren't, so my question is following:

is it safe to use following savepoint pattern in PostgreSQL or not:

```
savepoint s1;
select id from tbl where id=? for update nowait;
rollback to/release s1;
```

I do see it is not possible to avoid [XID growth](https://postgres.ai/blog/20210831-postgresql-subtransactions-considered-harmful#problem-1-xid-growth), however I'm not sure about it's performance impact, what about other pitfalls?

Comment: In both databases, both statements in session 2 throw errors. The spelling of the error message differs, but that doesn't seem like a meaningful difference.  There may be a more important difference, but your example different exemplify it.

Comment: @jjanes the Q is about keeping current transaction active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to use that pattern in that it will not produce wrong results or break the database, but it is guaranteed to lead to terrible performance. Do not set savepoints for each individual statement. You have to think more carefully and set them only where you really need them, that is, before statements that are expected to sometimes fail, but that shouldn't abort the transaction when they fail.

To answer your question, and to quote from my article: the process array, which is stored in shared memory and contains information about all currently running backends, has room for at most 64 non-aborted subtransactions per session. After that, the subtransaction IDs spill to disk, which is bad for performance. So don't set more than 64 savepoints per transaction, and remember that the PL/pgSQL construct `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` is implemented with a savepoint.

Comment: I'm not going to "protect" every statement, there is the only one which requires such trick: `select ... for update no wait`, I'm not going to create new tuples within subtransaction/savepoint, moreover, I have checked and releasing savepoint does not release row lock - does it still affect that 64 savepoint records limit?

Comment: Yes, because that subtransaction ID is associated with the row lock, so it has to be remembered.