# Postgres chocking on specific input

Tags: django, postgresql, unicode

I have a multi-lingual Django/Postgres-based app that fails on the following input (sanitized):

```
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "main_model" ("a_id", "b", "c", "d", "text", "f", "g", "h")
  VALUES (1, 2, 'c', 'd', '...nahlá<U+009A>ení ... nahla<U+009A>ování...', 'f', 'g', 'h')
  RETURNING "main_model"."id"
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

The `text` strings are in unicode, and it appears postgres is chocking on it. This is one example, but this is happening on several other languages as well.

Is there a better way to understand what the exact error on this statement is?

Is there any sanitation I need to do on the unicode strings before throwing them on the DB?

Comment: It's not **that** statement, it's some statement before that which threw an error and therefor you get the "current transaction is aborted".

Comment: Upvoted to balance out the downvote.. theres no reason to downvote this question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - ok, it would be awesome if you could explain how to see the failing statement. Because the logs show nothing right now.

Comment: @YuvalAdam: no idea. Shouldn't your application log that? Where is that statement coming from? If it's a script you might want to check that out.

Comment: This is a printout of the postgres log itself. I find it odd that it logs a subsequent error, but not the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled onto https://stackoverflow.com/a/10437521/24545

The lesson learned from this issue is to ensure there are no errors that are caught and not handled.

In my case I had a try/except block that was hiding a real error, and the next time it came up was a transaction error in postgres.

Comment: OK, you're talking about a try/except block in Python code talking to PostgreSQL. I was confused for a minute there an thought you were talking about PL/PgSQL.