# commands ignored until end of transaction blockcurrent transaction is aborted

Tags: django

Django keeps throwing the error below when i try to register an account with the application via [Django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) plugin. I am able to do crud operations with other models with no problems.

My env:
Postgresql 8.4
Django 1.4.2

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: POST Request URL:
>   localhost:8000/accounts/register/
>
> Django Version: 1.4.2 Python Version: 2.7.3 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.humanize', 
>   'django.contrib.gis',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'south', 
>   'dirapp',  'registration',  'django_extensions',  'sorl.thumbnail', 
>   'debug_toolbar') Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/root/posguide/registration/views.py" in register
>     187.             new_user = backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data) File "/root/posguide/registration/backends/default/**init**.py" in register
>     79.                                                                     password, site) File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in
>   inner
>     209.                 return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/root/posguide/registration/models.py" in create_inactive_user
>     78.         new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password) File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py"
>   in create_user
>     160.         user.save(using=self._db) File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
>   save
>     463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update) File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
>   save_base
>     565.                 created=(not record_exists), raw=raw, using=using) File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py"
>   in send
>     172.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named) File "/root/posguide/dirapp/views.py" in create_user_profile
>     154.        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance) File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py"
>   in create
>     137.         return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs) File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in
>   create
>     377.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db) File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
>   save
>     463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update) File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
>   save_base
>     551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw) File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py"
>   in _insert
>     203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs) File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in
>   insert_query
>     1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id) File
>   "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py"
>   in execute_sql
>     910.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> Exception Type: InternalError at /accounts/register/ Exception Value:
>   current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block

Comment: This typically means that there is a Database error which has occurred and you are trying to access the database after that. Are you doing any customization to the django-registration plugin?

Comment: Didn't touch djangp-registration plugin source at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979369/databaseerror-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra)