# TransactionManagementError?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hello thanks for reading. I am doing a quick site in Django and I have a very simple update statement in raw SQL I am making to my Postgres database. Something in here is making trouble:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection, transaction

def rsvp_update(request, rsvp_id, status):
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("UPDATE public.rsvp SET status=%s WHERE rsvp_id = %s", [status, rsvp_id])
  transaction.commit()
  return HttpResponse('okay')
```

I am getting an error that says "TransactionManagementError at [URL]
This code isn't under transaction management". Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [`commit_manually`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually) decorator for the code where you manage transactions manually.