# django - current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: python, django, database-integrity

```
try: 
   user = User.objects.create_user(_username, _email, pwd)
except IntegrityError, e:
   fail = e.message
   return render_to_response('register.html',{'reg_fail':fail},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have this code, once i catch the IntegrityError, i am getting this error: 
**current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block**

why is this? if i delete the `context_instance` part, then i am getting again the page but without any media access. I am stuck, i want just to register a user or if integrityError, then render to register page with error message.

**by the way**: i am using django1.4 and postgresql. and `User` is django's auth user

Answer (score 1):

With `user_create` you start transaction, and doing this again cause the error of not commited transaction.You have to commit(end) your transaction after `user_create` as follow:

```
try: 
   user = User.objects.create_user(_username, _email, pwd)
   user.full_clean()
   user.save()
except IntegrityError, e:
   fail = e.message
   return render_to_response('register.html',{'reg_fail':fail},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: oh, i thought, ``create_user`` will save automatically, doesnot it do?

Comment: No it don't. When you call create_user, you just create User object, full_clean is validating data and save is commit of transaction.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user  look at here

Comment: And as you can see there save() method is inserting data into db, user_create just create object.

Comment: not really, i see this sentence there: ``Creates, saves and returns a User.``

Comment: look here at save(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ "Django doesn’t hit the database until you explicitly call save()."

Comment: i know this, but not in my case, because ``create_user`` is a method of Django's User Model. see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#creating-users

Comment: Hmmm, you are right I just looked at source code of create_user and save method is called there. But everything works fine after adding save method call?

Comment: Try to make a rollback, someone got the same error with postgres:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979369/databaseerror-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra

Comment: yeaah, i am trying now :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a default database or couple database. it's recommended to use db_manager() to specify the database.
db_manager() returns a copy of the manager bound to the database you specify.

```
User.objects.db_manager(’new_users’).create_user(...)
```