# Django Shell and Django Web App giving different results

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that has been working okay and all of a sudden something seems to be broken.

```
class ClosedUserGroup(models.Model):
    """ Preset definitions for ClosedUserGroup:
    """
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        auto_now_add=True,
        null=True,
        default='2013-08-15 13:37:13.370030'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='<MISSING:CUG_NAME')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class Partner(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        auto_now_add=True,
        null=True,
        default=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='<MISSING:PARTNERNAME>')

class PartnerCug(models.Model):
    """ Partner to ClosedUserGroup relation
    """
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        auto_now_add=True,
        null=True,
        default='2013-08-15 13:37:13.370030'
    )
    partner = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    cug = models.ForeignKey(ClosedUserGroup)        

class Account(models.Model):
    """
        Account:
        TODO:DESCRIPTION
    """
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        auto_now_add=True,
        null=True,
        default=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    number = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(
        Partner,
        db_column='submitted_by'
    )
```

in django shell, the following commands run successfully and returns a result of 1:

```
from myapp.models import Account
account_object = Account.objects.filter(id=1)
account_object.filter(account__submitted_by__partnercug__cug=3).count()
```

However, in django itself, I have the function

```
def get_other_accounts():
    """get total accounts"""
    account_object = Account.objects.filter(id=1)
    total_accounts = account_object.filter(account__submitted_by__partnercug__cug=3).count()
```

This however fails with the error `DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block` and it points to the last line in that function. So its working django shell but not from the web app.

Comment: Tried after exiting shell?

Comment: look what you got in the two filters, it's not different ?

Comment: You know that in the shell you are counting `PartnerCug` objects and in the Django function you are counting `ClosedUserGroup` (cug) objects, whatever those might be?

Comment: first query have `account__submitted_by__partnercug` and second one have `account__submitted_by__partnercug` **__cug**

Comment: @FallenAngel I've edited that. It was a typo. Error still stands

Comment: @frnhr the query should return the number of accounts submitted by other entities in closed user group with that primary ID

Comment: My point was exactly the same as FallenAngel's, no nothing of it...

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979369

Comment: @GeorgeStocker using Postgresql

Comment: @Pathétique hmmm. thanks for that. Now checking to see if there are any error further up. But duplicate? In this case the code works in Django Shell but not in the webapp.

Comment: @lukik the error message is the same, the problem is the same.  Somewhere in your web application you have code that is throwing an error in the database.  The database is telling you, "Hey, I'm not doing anything else because I'm in an error state."

Answer (score 0):

Missing `id` or `pk` field (primary key) on `ClosedUserGroup` model?

I don't see how that could work in either shell or web.

Comment: The model didn't have but the fixtures had it so in the DB the primary ID is there.

Comment: Add it to the model then? Django shouldn't know of any DB columns that are not described by a `Field`, they could only cause problems