# PostgreSQL "DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I installed OSQA and I synchronized (`syncdb` and `migrate`) the databases and I restarted Apache.
In the browser I got the HTTP Status **200 Error** and in the project logs I got a lot of errors with this message:

```
DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I also found these errors in **PostgreSQL**'s logs:

```
LOG:  statement: SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'FORM_EMPTY_QUESTION_BODY' 
ERROR:  relation "forum_keyvalue" does not exist at character 85
STATEMENT:  SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'FORM_EMPTY_QUESTION_BODY' 
LOG:  statement: SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'FORM_MIN_NUMBER_OF_TAGS' 
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
STATEMENT:  SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'FORM_MIN_NUMBER_OF_TAGS' 
LOG:  statement: SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'FORM_MAX_NUMBER_OF_TAGS' 
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
STATEMENT:  SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'FORM_MAX_NUMBER_OF_TAGS' 
LOG:  statement: SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'FORM_EMPTY_QUESTION_BODY' 
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
STATEMENT:  SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'FORM_EMPTY_QUESTION_BODY' 
LOG:  statement: SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH' 
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
STATEMENT:  SELECT "forum_keyvalue"."id", "forum_keyvalue"."key", "forum_keyvalue"."value" FROM "forum_keyvalue" WHERE "forum_keyvalue"."key" = 'MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH' 
LOG:  statement: SELECT "forum_badge"."id" FROM "forum_badge"
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I searched for a solution to the problem on StackOverflow and [I found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979369/databaseerror-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra):

> To get rid of the error, roll back the last (erroneous) transaction
>   after you've fixed your code:
>
> `from django.db import transaction transaction.rollback()`

This solution doesn't work for me. 
I running my application on Python2.7, Django-1.3.7 and PostgreSQL 9.1.11.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you verify that the table `forum_keyvalue` exists in the database?  Because the first error you list says that it can't find the table.

Comment: Thank you EWit, the table exists: `osqa_db=# select exists(select relname from pg_class where relname = 'forum_keyvalue' and relkind='r');
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)`

Comment: Maybe Django created your tables in wrong database. Connect to your database using `psql` and just use `\d+ forum_keyvalue`. If it is there then your application is connecting to wrong database. Also: HTTP status 200 is not an error - it means `OK`.

Comment: Doesn't the `f` in `?column? ---------- f` imply non-existence? As in it does not exist?

Comment: Can you run: `SELECT * FROM forum_keyvalue;` using `./manage.py dbshell`? Since it is also possible that the table exists but is in an unused database.