# Proper use of serialization with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg

I am accessing a postgresql table with serialization transaction isolation.  I am doing something like this (with an existing psycopg2 connection `conn` and cursor in that connection, `cur`:

```
while True:
  try:
    cur.execute(query)
    break
  except TransactionRollbackError:
    [sleep a little]
    continue
  except Exception:
    [handle error here]
```

The point of this is to retry in case of serialization contention.  Now, this works fine much of the time.  But often I get this error after it has spent one iteration in the `TransactionRollbackError` trap:

`current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`.  Apparently, spinning this way to avoid serialization contention is not appropriate?  Should I be doing this a different way?

Some notes: I am accessing the table with different processes (that are all the same and doing the same things: selecting, incrementing, and updating / inserting into the table.)  Each of these processes has their own connection `conn`, they are not sharing a connection.

Another note: it seems like after going through the `TransactionRollbackError` exception block once, in the next spin of the while loop it ends up in the `Exception` exception block instead.

Still another note:  The number of processes running at the same time has a direct effect on the frequency of errors, in that more processes tends to produce more errors.  So there is some kind of contention going on.  I am under the impression that using serialized transaction isolation with retries (as in my demo code) would fix this.

Comment: Do you [`rollback` the connection](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.rollback) in the `except TransactionRollbackError` branch?

Comment: @musically_ut - I do not, I think that I shouldn't.  Am I wrong?

Comment: `conn.rollback()` is the way I recover from errors to continue using my cursors after I commit a typo in `cur.execute`'s argument. A cursory reading of the error message suggests that the transaction ought to be aborted as well and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13007379/987185) suggests doing something similar. Why do you think you **should not** rollback?

Comment: @musically_ut - My (maybe dumb) assumption was that since it's an error due to serialization contention, that I could simply retry without rolling back.  I will try to make a savepoint and rollback / recover.

Comment: You don't need to create a save-point explicitly. Each independent `execute` is run inside a transaction and it is that transaction that your connection gets trapped in if the statement runs into problems. Just doing a `conn.rollback()` in the correct branch should suffice.

Comment: @musically_ut - The reason I want to use savepoints is that by the time I get to this problematic code, I may have already executed a few SQL statements that I don't want to rollback.  In that case I should be using savepoints, correct?

Comment: Yes, unless you put the connection in autocommit mode. However, your other code should also be wrapped inside a `try/catch`. More details here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control

Comment: @musically_ut - I have reasons for not using autocommit (specifically, if something in the chain of sql commands fails, I want them all to fail.)  Would you please put your solution above in an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: It would be better if you can confirm that it works first. :)

Comment: @musically_ut - Yes, it solves the problem I was having.  Thanks.  Now I've run into another problem that I'll put in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765494/serialization-contention-in-postgresql-bringing-my-process-to-a-grind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should perform a [`rollback`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.rollback) in the `except TransactionError:` branch to recover from the error state:

```
while True:
  try:
    cur.execute(query)
    break
  except TransactionRollbackError:
    conn.rollback()
    [sleep a little]
    continue
  except Exception:
    [handle error here]
```

This is the [recommendation made the FAQ as well](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html).

Note that it will rollback **all** the SQL commands thus far unless you have been doing your own transaction control or have the connection in `autocommit` mode.