# Can't insert data into sql table from scrapy items

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

These are the errors:

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'level': None,
 'school': 'Some school name',
 'place': None,
 'subject': None}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reducedgosling/.virtualenvs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/reducedgosling/Programming/schools/pipelines.py", line 28, in process_item
    self.cur.execute(sql, data)
psycopg2.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

items.py

```
class SchoolsItem(scrapy.Item):
    subject = scrapy.Field()
    level = scrapy.Field()
    place = scrapy.Field()
    school = scrapy.Field()
```

spider.py

```
def parse_school(self, response):
    item = SchoolsItem()
    school = response.css('h1 span.title::text').extract_first()
    table_rows = response.css('tr')
    for x in table_rows:
        item['subject'] = x.css('td.views-field-title a::text').extract_first()
        item['level'] = x.css('td.views-field-field-level').xpath('normalize-space(./text())').extract_first()
        item['place'] = x.css('td.views-field-field-campus').xpath('normalize-space(./text())').extract_first()
        item['school'] = school
        yield item
```

pipelines.py

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    sql = "INSERT INTO udir_content (subject, level, school, place) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
    data = (item['subject'], item['level'], item['school'], item['place'])
    self.cur.execute(sql, data)
    self.connection.commit()
    return item
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspected the Null values, which Python(or psycopg?) transforms into None values? But PostgreSQL accepts null values unless I specify NOT NULL, right?

The first error that shows in the psql log file is this:

```
ERROR:  relation "udir_content" does not exist at character 13
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO udir_content (subject, level, school, place) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'Some school name', NULL);
```

The rest just says "transaction aborted".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979369/databaseerror-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Is your table `udir_content` named using all lower case in the DB? You need to match it exactly (case sensitive).

Comment: @Tony yes, all lower case and no quotation marks

Comment: The next thing to check is if you are using schemas? Is the table in the default schema or a different one you created?

Comment: @Tony, Heh, I just spent two hours only to realize now that i was inside the postgres database when i created the tables, when i fixed it, i just needed to grant permissions to my second user and now everything is fine.

Comment: Good to know you found the answer. When you can, mark your own answer as 'accepted' so others know you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your INSERT, the error reported is because the insert has failed and you have not rolled back the transaction before issuing another.

The `execute` should use question marks as placeholders (`?`) not `%s`

So for your statement you should use

```
sql = "INSERT INTO udir_content (subject, level, school, place) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"
```

Comment: I changed it but get this error: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...dir_content (subject level, school, place) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)...

Comment: Apologies, I'm using SQLite and that is happy with `?`, for Postgres it seems you were correct with `%s`. However, you still need to test your SQL statement for errors. Call `mogrify()` to get the sql statement being executed and test it against your database to see what error you are getting - http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question with error from psql log file.

Answer (score 0):

Learned a little about PostgreSQL the hard way by spending two hours just to figure out I created the table inside the postgres database.. not the one I created for this. Then I had to grant my second user privileges and now everything is fine.